# Verify if a disabled user account has a shared mailbox

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

A co-worker and I are trying to develop a script that will show us shared mailboxes attached to a disabled user account and when the account was disabled by looking at the Last password change date time property on their AD account in Azure. When we run this half the time it only grabs the info for the shared mailboxes attached to disabled user the other it pulls no data to the csv. Any help is appreciated.

```
$DisabledUsers = Get-AzureADUser -Filter {(Enabled -eq $False)} | Select-Object  Lastpasswordchangedatetime
$SharedInboxes = Get-Mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails SharedMailbox $Results = @()
Foreach ($SharedInbox in $SharedInboxes)`
    {
  $InboxPermissions = Get-MailboxPermission -Identity $SharedInbox.Identity | Where-Object {$_.User.ToString().Split("\")[1] -in $DisabledUsers}
  If ($InboxPermissions)
  {
    $Result = [PSCustomObject]@{
      SharedInbox = $SharedInbox.Identity
      DisabledUser = $InboxPermissions.User.ToString().Split("\")[1]
    }
    $Results += $Result
  }
} $Results | Export-Csv -Path "C:\SharedInboxforDisabledAccounts.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Expected a csv to generate with the mailboxes attached to disabled users and the date the password was last changed on the account indicating when the user was disabled